# Building new Pc: First boot displays:"Reboot and Select proper Boot drive"

Tags: computer-building

**Edit I removed the m.2 incase it wasn't installed correctly and replaced with a sata drive, no change..**

Most of the solutions I find are assuming the OS and other functions are already installed.
I'm new to pc building this is my first build.
Ryzen 2700, wraith cooler, b450 gibabyte aorus pro wifi rev 1.0 motherboard. phantek p300, amd 580 gpu, corsair 750 psu, m.2 500gb, 32 gb ram ripjaws (2x16gb). Motherboard Manual can be selected from:https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10/support#support-manual

Basically I boot it up, the lights turnon and everything looks okay...then first message displayed on the monitor is "Reboot and Select proper Boot drive". I don't know if this is normal or not, but based on what my motherboard manual says and the guide I follow it says the bios menu should loadup.....and that u need to get into the bios first! I tried ctrl+alt+delete but that just brought me back after a couple seconds. I tried spamming delete when computer first loads. Tried spamming it during ctrl alt delete etc, nothing.

On the hardware side: I went into the case...I took the ram out and put it back in again, making sure both sides of each stick snapped in. With the ram I'm supposedly using the right spots, although I find it confusing. it lists channel A as 2,4 and channel B as 1,3 but in the chart and on the motherboard its listed as 4231. Where 4 is the closest slot to the cpu. The recommended is 1 and 2, so I used those slots. So my ram is farthest from the board with 1 slot blank inbetween....the opposite of what msi and most boards I've seen would have me do.

The only thing not connected to my case is something labelled for led use only...I have no idea what it does or where it goes its a 4 pin connector, I'm pretty sure its just for led though it has a sticker on it saying to only connect it to phantek led wires. I'd consult my manual but there is NO MANUAL FOR P300 PHANTEK CAse. Just a quickstart guide with no mention of the wires...

I'm at a loss atm. The only thing I can think of to try is that maybe my m.2 wasn't installed correctly. It didn't 'snap' into place at all and just kinda sat there, I wasn't sure during installation but I couldn't get it to snap in either. I inserted it at a 30 degree angle....pushed in...it just kinda sat there and some of the yellow connector could still be seen. I pushed it down and put the screw back ontop. Was it supposed to make a snapping sound when its pushed properly inplace while on that 30 degree angle? Was I supposed to wiggle it or something? I tried applying alot of force I remember, but that was the best I could get it. Having experienced what is required for ram and my gpu....I think its worth a try re-installing if there is no other suggestion.

Since the monitor is working, I think the gpu is probably working okay. It snapped right into place and has the safety smap. I'm not sure what else to do. I had a sata 2tb but I took it out and removed the wire connecting it to the mobo out of the case as well, taking it out of the equation made no change tho.

in terms of the cords from the powersupply and mobo: cpu fan connected to mobo in the cpu fan slot; case fan connected to motherboard in fan slot#2 (number 1 is unused atm), the 24pin is connected to the mobo; the cpu pin thing from the psu is connected to the mobo (upper left corner); the 8 pin from teh psu is connected to the gpu and the dvi cable is connected to the monitor from the gpu's dvi port; the little 2 pin case power and misc case wires are inserted along with the case's usb one etc....the only dangling wire from the case is that "connect to phantek led only" 4 pin (it has another 4 pin like it connected to the wire as if its for 2 outputs like the gpu is).

There's a video showing the error at the beginning https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WBjF4Ijvj4....but he in this example is using a pc that is already windows installled etc...I tried what he tried minus the end bit.

Answer (score 2):

Press Delete to access the BIOS, just after you turn it on.

I usually find it works best if you press it once per second, until it loads.

[image]

That's from page 23 of the [manual](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_b450-aorus-pro-wifi_1002_e_190528.pdf).

Maybe your case's front USB ports aren't connected internally yet. Try plugging your keyboard into a USB port on the back!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97047/discussion-on-answer-by-wrecclesham-building-new-pc-first-boot-displaysreboot).